# Java: Double-Click a JSlider to Reset

Tags: java, swing, reset, double-click, jslider

I have a JSlider that sets the speed of my metronome, from 40 - 200, where 120 is the default, in the middle.

When the user clicks the metronome button, the metronome plays at the speed displayed on the JSlider - the user drags the slider to the right, the speed of the metronome increases, and it decreases if they slide it to the left.

How do I add functionality so that if the user double-clicks on the JSlider button, it defaults back to 120 - in the middle?

Here is my code:

```
public Metronome() {
    tempoChooser = new JSlider();
    metronomeButton = new JToggleButton();

    JLabel metText = new JLabel("Metronome:");
    add(metText);

    ...

    tempoChooser.setMaximum(200);
    tempoChooser.setMinimum(40);
    tempoChooser.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            tempoChooserStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    add(tempoChooser);
    ...
    }

private void tempoChooserStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    final int tempo = tempoChooser.getValue();
    if (((JSlider) evt.getSource()).getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        setMetronomeButtonText(tempo);
    } else {
        processTempoChange(tempo);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

You need to read up on that and implement MouseListener. You can use `int getClickCount()` to count how many times the user has clicked, which will help you read double clicks.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Even though I dont see a question, my gues is you are looking for `MouseListener`.

Comment: See answer of m92, and please don't use one of the answers involving timers.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple job, you have to add [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and listening if during fixed period Mouse cliked once or twice times, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290045/714968)

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote something similar so I could differentiate between single and double left mouse-button clicks:

```
private Timer timer;
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() { // timer expired before another click received, therefore = single click
                    this.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                    /* single-click actions in here */
                }

            }, (Integer) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval"));
        }
        else { // received another click before previous click (timer) expired, therefore = double click
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
            /* double-click actions in here */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please no. `getClickCount() ` is your friend.

Comment: @stryba that's right, although getClickCount() will still return two single clicks for every double-click, so I needed to differentiate between those two single clicks and an 'actual' single click.

Comment: your are right, in that case you'd have to involve a `Timer`, even though I think this should be somehow abstracted/abstractable by `Swing` though.