# awt.TrayIcon is it posible to distinguish between a double click on the tray icon and a close of a balloon message?

Tags: java, awt, jruby, actionlistener, system-tray

Currently in my (JRuby code), I want to handle "balloon close" messages differently than "double click on the tray icon" (awt.TrayIcon instance):

```
import java.awt.TrayIcon
import java.awt.event.MouseListener

tray = java.awt.SystemTray::system_tray
image = java.awt.Toolkit::default_toolkit.get_image('')

trayIcon = TrayIcon.new(image, 'name', nil)

tray.add(trayIcon)
trayIcon.addActionListener do |evt|
  puts "in here", evt.id
end
trayIcon.displayMessage("title", "try clicking within the baloon, but not the x, then double clicking the tray icon", TrayIcon::MessageType::INFO)
puts "try clicking within the balloon message, or double clicking, both seem to generate the same event"
```

and the equivalent code in java https://gist.github.com/4338167

it seems that this action listener gets called either when 1) a user double clicks the icon in the system tray, or 2) a user closes a tray's recent balloon message by clicking on the balloon (not on the x).

Is it possible to distinguish between the 2 different event types (both seem to have event id 1001), or must I just infer it by timing relative or something else? Or can I somehow "know" that the balloon is still up, and thus the click must have come from it?

Comment: please I lost in Ruby, are we talking about [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html), or post an SSCCE, no issue to determine double click or mouseevents to Message, a few times I'm answered for AWT / Swing

Comment: ok added jruby and java example (and yes).  My question is not how to determine double click, but more how to determine when a balloon is closed *versus* a double click, both seem to send the same message...

Comment: [have to convert to JRuby](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460383/714968), or [another here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6290045/714968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`TrayIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) seems to imply that clicking on the balloon message can trigger an `ActionEvent`, which is the same as, for your case, double-clicking on the icon itself.

You may need to add a mouse listener to trigger on clicks, and if a click event is followed by an `ActionEvent` within some small period then it's a double-click, otherwise it's a click on the message being displayed. By choosing a sufficiently small interval, you should be able to properly distinguish them.

Comment: Yeah I figured something like this might be necessary...trying to "time" how long it has taken since the last click occurred, etc...thanks!

Comment: I had the same question (in a Java program), and noticed that empirically, the click on the balloon is accompanied by the 1024 bit being on in the event's modifiers field.  But I don't know what to make of it -- 1024 = TEXT_EVENT_MASK, which doesn't make much sense. But I also noticed that Shift and other modifiers show up differently than documented (e.g., Shift should be value of SHIFT_MASK (1), but it appears as 64).