# How to Run application in background when close the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, system-tray

I used a **system tray** in my java application. I want to **disappear the GUI** and run the application in **background**, but system tray must remain available when user click on **close** button of JFrame.

Comment: Don't set the frame to EXIT_ON_CLOSE or call System.exit when the frame is closed.  The event dispatching thread will continue to run until the JVM is terminated

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's the right answer - in fact, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @adrian Cause its to early in the morning and I need another cup if tea :P

Comment: Please have a look at this related example, How to [hide JFrame in SystemTray of TaskBar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7461477/1057230)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to disappear the GUI and run the application in background, but
>   system tray must remain available when user click on close button of
>   JFrame.

- set proper [JFrames method for `DefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29), `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`, by default implemented in API

Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates a "close" on this frame. You must specify one of the following choices:

> DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the
>   windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
>
> HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
>
> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener
>   objects.
>
> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.
>
> The value is set to HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default. Changes to the value of
>   this property cause the firing of a property change event, with
>   property name "defaultCloseOperation".

- then from [`SystemTray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) to call `JFrame.setVisible(true)`, this event is accesible from

  1. [`TrayIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29)
  2. [`JPopupMenu added to SystemTray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290045/714968)

Answer (score 1):

**Posting this as an answer**

Just like MadProgrammer said:

> Don't set the frame to EXIT_ON_CLOSE or call System.exit when the frame is closed. The event dispatching thread will continue to run until the JVM is terminated

Answer (score 0):

You can have the System Tray available in a separate thread.

Comment: That's a very dangerous suggestion

Comment: Even though TrayIcon is a AWT component, it still relies on and uses the Event Dispatching Thread. This could cause updates to UI to executed out side the context of the EDT. Better to put the none UI processing in a separate thread instead

Comment: What he said... I just spent a week troubleshooting defects caused by calling Swing methods from outside EDT. These things take forever to track down if you don't pay attention to it up front.

Answer (score -1):

if I do not understand bad you want a background app with availability to see GUI in any moment:

1. You can set your frame as HIDE_ON_CLOSE when you click 'X' button in your window
2. You need create a code similar like this:
3. Check that we have 2 buttons with different actions

   ```
    try {            
        Main_view frame = new Main_view();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            TrayIcon trayIcon = null;

            //Listener for exit button
            ActionListener ExitListener = new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   System.exit(0);
               }
             };

             //Listener for display button
             ActionListener DisplayListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
             };

              //Menu when you right click the icon
              PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

              //Buttons to show
              MenuItem displayButton = new MenuItem("Display");
              MenuItem exitButton = new MenuItem("Exit");

              //add the previous actions made it
              exitButton.addActionListener(ExitListener);
              displayButton.addActionListener(DisplayListener);

              //add to the popup
              popup.add(displayButton);
              popup.add(exitButton);

              // URL: MyProject/src/MyGUI/check.png 
              // Small icon on secondary taskbar
              Image image= ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/MyGUI/check.png"));
              trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "App name", popup);
              trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);


              trayIcon.addActionListener(DisplayListener);
              trayIcon.addActionListener(ExitListener);

              try {
                   tray.add(trayIcon);

                  } catch (AWTException e) {

                         System.err.println(e);
                     }
                     // ...
                 } else {
                     // disable tray option in your application or
                     // perform other actions
                 }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   ```

### Results

[image]

Comment: Almost all the code was extracted from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html 
If you have a Java Name convention to share please do it, could be useful